# Streamwriter (cannot type full text) c#

Tags: streamwriter

the problem is when I print data to "M100.csv" file, I only see the only one line of:

```
                    writer1.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}",
                    houses[i].District, houses[i].Street, houses[i].Number,
                    houses[i].Type, houses[i].Years, houses[i].Area, houses[i].Rooms);
                    writer1.WriteLine("\n");
```

"writer1" must print two lines of different houses, however it prints only one. I'm sure my other methods work fine.
Also I do not see this line:

```
             writer.WriteLine("{0} {1}","Duomenys apie visus murinius namus, kuriu plotas yra daugiau nei 100kv.m. :\n",
             "Rajonas \t Gatve \t Numeris \t Tipas \t Metai \t Plotas \t Kambariu skaicius \n");
             writer.WriteLine("\n");
```

Full code:

```
public static void Print(Houses[] houses,int amount, int[] BrickHouseNumber,int[] BlockHouseNumber)
    {

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Andrius\\Desktop\\Mokslams\\C#\\Pratybos\\P2\\P2.4\\M100.csv"))
         {
             writer.WriteLine("{0} {1}","Duomenys apie visus murinius namus, kuriu plotas yra daugiau nei 100kv.m. :\n",
             "Rajonas \t Gatve \t Numeris \t Tipas \t Metai \t Plotas \t Kambariu skaicius \n");
             writer.WriteLine("\n");
         }
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            if (BrickHouseNumber[i] > 0)
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer1 = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Andrius\\Desktop\\Mokslams\\C#\\Pratybos\\P2\\P2.4\\M100.csv"))
                {
                    writer1.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}",
                    houses[i].District, houses[i].Street, houses[i].Number,
                    houses[i].Type, houses[i].Years, houses[i].Area, houses[i].Rooms);
                    writer1.WriteLine("\n");
                 }
            }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Declaring StreamWriter with the path-only constructor will either create or overwrite the file at the location. Since you're creating a new stream writer for each write, you are effectively truncating and restarting the file, and ultimately end with a single line of text. Without restructuring your code, you can fix this behavior by changing the constructor to append rather than overwrite by passing true to constructor overload.

```
 new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Andrius\\Desktop\\Mokslams\\C#\\Pratybos\\P2\\P2.4\\M100.csv", true)
```

Additionally, the WriteLine method will automatically add line endings. Using `WriteLine("\n")` adds, assuming a windows environment, a line feed, a carriage return, and another line feed. This is going to lead to a lot of white-space.